# Jquery parsing JSON response

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery function - this is the response that is it is getting

```
   {"d":"{\"res\":\"\\u003cdiv class=\\\"accordian_head\\\"\\u003e\\u003cdiv class=\\\"plus\\\"\\u003e\\u003c/div\\u00..........."NewTags\":\"\\........
```

when the response is just {"d":" response..." }  I have no trouble reading it in jQuery with just msg.d  - but here I have "res" : "text" nested in "d"  , so how to I read res out of this response ?   I tried

```
      success: function (msg) {
                    var obj = unescape(msg.d);
                    var res = unescape(obj.res);
                    var newtags = unescape(obj.NewTags);
```

Where the sample JSON I pasted is msg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$.parseJSON(msg.d)
```

This will unescape the quotes and parse the string to JSON.

Comment: I tried parseJSON(msg.d)  - I was missing $ , this works great!

Answer (score 1):

when you get `d` it returns a string. You need an object to then access it's `res` property. Try this:

```
success: function (msg) {
                    var obj = eval(unescape(msg.d));
                    var res = unescape(obj.res);
                    var newtags = unescape(obj.NewTags);
```

Depending on what unescape does, you might want to try just `eval(msg.d)`

If eval doesn't work, try [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run msg.d through [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

It would be even better if you could tweak the server script to return it as a nested JSON instead.